# Modbus Checksum Error using minimalmodbus python library with Waveshare RS485 CAN HAT (B) on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, modbus, minimalmodbus

I am trying to use the minimalmodbus library to read register values from an industrial sensor called an [ICM](https://www.mpfiltriusa.com/products/contamination-monitoring-products/icm-20.html) by company MP Filtri. I am using the Waveshare RS485 CAN HAT (B) connected on top of a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

When I try to read a register, I get a Checksum error response as follows (username redacted because it contains my family name):
[image: Checksum Error]

I am using an external 24VDC power source to supply power to both the Waveshare Hat (which powers the Pi) as well as the MP Filtri ICM Sensor. The A and B wires of the sensor are correctly connected to the A and B terminals of "RS485_0" on the Waveshare Hat. The Sensor and the Pi/hat share the same power source and the grounds are connected.

I've configured the Waveshare hat as it shows in the [Waveshare wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RS485_CAN_HAT_(B)) under the "Install Libraries" and the "Driver Configuration" sections. Once the driver is configured in /boot/config.txt as described, I can then see the devices have been added to /dev as ttySC0 and ttySC1. Also, I ran the suggested command `dmesg | grep -i '\(can\|spi\)'` and get the following output:
[GREP SPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VZo0.jpg)
**This is important to note because you will see in the code below, the only baud rate that I can get to return anything is 921600 as it shows in this screenshot for ttySC0 and ttySC1

The Modbus section of the ICM sensor's manual shows the following setup information:

> 3.1 Modbus Settings
>
> Protocol type RTU (not ASCII)
> Data Bits 8
> Stop Bits 1
> Parity Required, Even
> Baud Auto-sensing 1200-115200
> Signalling RS485
> Node Address 204 (or user set)
> 3.2 Communications Check
> You should be able to read the product ID code from register 0 (from Modbus node address 204). The product ID code is the value 54237 (decimal) or 0xD3DD (hexadecimal).

When writing the Python script to read register 0 from the sensor (Product ID), I used the basic code from the minimalmodbus docs. I also used the Modbus slave address of 4, which is set in the device. The document page above states that address 204 can be used as a permanent address, but an address can also be set in the device that it will respond on as well. I've tried both with the same results, but in the event that more devices are added to the bus at a later date, I am using the salve address set in the device which is 4. The code that I am using in a file called basic.py is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import minimalmodbus

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttySC0', 4, debug = True)  # port name, slave address (in decimal)

instrument.serial.baudrate = 921600             # Baud
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8                  # bytesize
instrument.serial.parity   = minimalmodbus.serial.PARITY_EVEN
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1                  # stop bits
instrument.serial.timeout  = 0.5                # seconds
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU        # rtu or ascii mode
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True

## Read Product ID From Register 0 ##
prodid = instrument.read_register(0, 0)  # Registernumber, number of decimals
print(prodid)
```

The response that I receive is a checksum error as shown above and also here again:
[image: Checksum Error]

Why am I receiving this checksum error message and how do eliminate this error? Also, why is the only baud rate that works 921600? Is that because the base baud of ttySC0 is showing up as this rate?

Comment: "only baud rate that works 921600" - getting a corrupt response does not really mean its working! The docs say the sensor supports 1200-115200 (so not 921600; the waveshare should support 300~921600).

Comment: I tried a few different baud rates. The default was 9600. I tried the minimum of 1200, the maximum of 115200, and a few in between. All of them give the response in debug mode  that the device expects to receive 7 bytes back but it receives 0. It also ends with:  "raise NoResponseError("No communication with the instrument (no answer)")
minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)

Comment: OK - unfortunately there are a lot of variables here so solving this can take time (I generally connect to devices from a PC with a known good RS485 adaptor first). Firstly node address; the manual screenshot you include above says `204` but you have used `4` (which matches the full manual you linked) please confirm settings (worth adding current settings to your question rather than relying on the manual access settings on the device). There is also a "Diagnostics Display" on the device that should tell you how many chars it has received (good for verifying comms).

Comment: I've edited the post by changing the photo of the manual text to a blockquote. I also added notation describing the node address used being address 4 as the set address in the device, but also that address 204 is a hard coded address that can also be used. Neither option makes any difference. Also to note: The diagnostics display shows "char errors" when running the python program, which can vary from 1-4 char errors. It also shows frames received, accepted, and sent. The received frames varies from 1-4, but accepted and sent remain at 0.

Comment: And what baudrate does it show (first check is ensuring the device is detecting the baudrate you are using). I don't think that this is going to be a good fit for stackoverflow because there are too many unknowns (i.e. the issue may just be that you need to run an earth connection) and stackoverflow is not setup for discussions;

Comment: The sensor tries different bauds, but never actually connects. I think that there might be some issue with the data that minimalmodbus is sending or I somehow have it configured wrong. I will keep trying or maybe just switch to another library altogether.  I'm about to give up on it completely. Thanks for the help.

Comment: My guess is it's a wiring issue, but obviously its difficult to diagnose that via the comments. I'd recommend using a command line tool (such as [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll) or [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) (you want to remove as many variables as possible so using a tool that is known to work means you know it's not due to an issue in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many different options, baud rates, coding, and multiple exchanges with Waveshare's customer service department, I finally came to a very simple solution to my question.

The Waveshare RS485 CAN HAT (B) has jumpers on each of the two RS485 channels that enable a 120 ohm resistor by default. Waveshare's customer service suggested trying without the resistors enabled, as they are not always needed on RS-485 communication (according to them). As soon as i removed the jumper, the program responded and I was able to read registers from the sensor.

Comment: They do mention this in [their FAQ](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/USB_TO_RS485#accordion3); bit unexpected (RS485 generally works without termination over short distances; but I did not think that having the termination would be an issue)